# Tkinter How to cut widgets and labels that go beyond frame width?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, widget, frame

In my Code the user can add text and widgets to a Frame. Sometimes the row ends with a combobox, sometimes with a label.
Sometimes these widgets go beyond the Frame.
Is there any way to place widgets like Combobox in second row and to cut labels at the end of the frame and place the rest of it also in the second row.
Thanks for help!
[image]

Working minimal code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re
import tkinter

root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, True)
bframe = Frame(root, width=300, height=50)
bframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)
bframe.grid_propagate(False)

linelist1 = ['some long text 1 as a label', '@combo@Aa Bb Cc Dd', 'some long text 2 as a label', 'some long text 3 as a label', '@combo@Ee Ff Gg Hh', 'some long text 4 as a label']
lines_with_combobox = [e for e, s in enumerate(linelist1) if '@combo@' in s]

for line in range(0, len(linelist1)):
    if line in lines_with_combobox:
        delete_combo_marker = re.split("@combo@", linelist1[line])
        words = delete_combo_marker.pop(0)
        word_as_values = re.split('\s+', delete_combo_marker[0])
        combobox = ttk.Combobox(bframe,width=10, values=word_as_values)
        combobox.grid(row=0, column=line, sticky= W)
    else:
        text = linelist1[line]
        Labeltext = ttk.Label(bframe, justify=LEFT ,text=text, wraplength=730)
        Labeltext.grid(row=0, column=line, sticky = W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: #root.resizable(False, True)
bframe = Frame(root, width=80, height=100)

Comment: combobox.grid(row=line1, column=1, sticky= W) and Labeltext.grid(row=line, column=0, sticky = W). I got 4 labels and 2 combox

Comment: Do you require actual columns? For example, if a combobox wraps to the second row and it's widget than the label, so the column grow? In other words, do you require a literal grid, or is your requirement just a list of rows with content that varies in size?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. I just found in line 12. Something is missing keyword.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley there are long rows of widgets. What i need is a way to detect the end of the frame and then wrap the widgets that get out of the frame into another row.

Comment: So, to be clear, you _don't_ need columns, you just want widgets to wrap?

Comment: No, i dont need columnd i need the widgets to wrap. But i need som kind of way to mark the position of the widget. And until now i used columns to find out the location of the widget in the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for putting widgets in a row and having them wrap when they do not fit is to use a text widget to manage the other widgets. A text widget has wrapping features built in.

Here's an example that creates a couple of rows of widgets that need to wrap. Once the UI opens, you can resize it to see the widgets dynamically adjust to the width of the window.

```
import tkinter as tk

data = """
The cow is of bovine ilk;
One end is moo, the other is milk.
"""

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, wrap="char", background=root.cget("background"))
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for line in data.strip().split("\n"):
    for word in line.split(" "):
        label = tk.Button(text, text=word)
        text.window_create("end", window=label)
    text.insert("end", "\n")
text.configure(state="disabled")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of unwrapped widgets]
[image: screenshot of wrapped widgets]

Comment: This is almost the perfect solution. The only problem ist that I rely heavily on grid column information with .grid_info(), to later get the postion of the widget. But ill just use textvariable=line and the solution you gave. Thanks alot.

Comment: do you know any way to connect additional information like the line to a widget. like v = label['information_variable']

Comment: @Kazkuris Each widget can be a class based on a frame, with as much other information and other widgets as you want.

Comment: @Kazkuris This solution doesn't put the widgets in a grid. Your question was unclear on whether you needed a grid or just a row that wraps. This gives you the ability to create a row that wraps.